# MCC: Synced text field has changed length in Sales Cloud, but not in MC - options to update?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Summary:

1. Using Marketing Cloud Connect (MCC) to sync data from Sales Cloud to
   Marketing Cloud.
2. A synced Text field on a synced object has been changed from 4 to 5 characters on the field settings in Sales Cloud.
3. This change has not occurred in Marketing Cloud (MC) even after refreshing the synced object.
4. MC Support advises: "the synchronized data extension schema is created only once at the time of object sync. later values are only added or replaced unfortunately there is no workaround apart from removing object and resyncing it."
5. This object is fundamental to the MC system, has automations, filters, SQL queries, DEs etc based on it.
6. Concern is that removing and then re-adding the synced object will result in issues with the automations, filters, SQL queries, DEs etc

Has anyone solved this issue or can advise on best practice? Or completed this removal and re-adding of an object and either had or not had issues?

Comment: Have you considered/tried to remove synced Text field and then re-sync it? It would remove the field from Synced DE and then add it back with the recent configuration.

Comment: Hi Niko - no we havn't tried that option as we get the warning: 
"Removing fields may result in loss of data and can affect any objects within the system that is associated with it.". Currently this seems like the lowest risk option, but I was hoping to find a no risk option!

Comment: Hello @Foweyboy, that is the usual warning message you get when you are removing a synced field. Just before going further with removal, consider all places where this particular field is used and then just continue with the removal. It has a risk only based on your own carefulness.